# How to backfill an interval from first value to last once answering a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to identify incline/decile if a column. So, in order to achieve this, I create a data frame with some values and conditions. The goal is to get the 2 res_e1,res_e2 following this logic:

if condition1 is met, the row is relevant, otherwise the value is NaN
if relevant - take the first row value and the last value and decrease the last from the first.
the results is either <0 or >0 for the entire interval.
In the example below, e1 relevant values **are idx 2 and idx 8**, the corresponding values are **4,3** and therefore in res_e1 all True relevant rows are marked with 3-4 < 0 => **"-"**
The same for e2, the values are **3,8** for the same indexes, the entire interval is **"+"**
Of course this should apply to all "True" intervals in the df

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'e1': [1,2,4,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,0],
    'e2': [1,2,3,4,3,2,-5,-10,8,10,11],
    'condition1': ['A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','A','A']
})
mask_c = df.condition1 == 'B'
df['relevant'] = mask_c

df['res_e1'] = ['NaN','NaN','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','NaN','NaN']
df['res_e2'] = ['NaN','NaN','+','+','+','+','+','+','+','NaN','NaN']

print(df)
```

After print:

```
    e1  e2 condition1  relevant res_e1 res_e2
0    1   1          A     False    NaN    NaN
1    2   2          A     False    NaN    NaN
2    4   3          B      True      -      +
3    4   4          B      True      -      +
4    5   3          B      True      -      +
5    6   2          B      True      -      +
6    5  -5          B      True      -      +
7    4 -10          B      True      -      +
8    3   8          B      True      -      +
9    2  10          A     False    NaN    NaN
10   0  11          A     False    NaN    NaN
```

I have tried to add a mask in order to detect the relevant frames, and some aggregation methods but I have no pretty way to get the first and last relevant values only and "color" the entire interval with their values.
I added 2 examples e1,e2 and results res_e1, res_e2 just to simplify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df = df.join(
 df[df['relevant']]
 .groupby(df['condition1'])[['e1', 'e2']]
 .transform(lambda s: '+' if s.iloc[-1]-s.iloc[0]>0 else '-')
 .add_prefix('res_')
)
```

Output:

```
    e1  e2 condition1  relevant res_e1 res_e2
0    1   1          A     False    NaN    NaN
1    2   2          A     False    NaN    NaN
2    4   3          B      True      -      +
3    4   4          B      True      -      +
4    5   3          B      True      -      +
5    6   2          B      True      -      +
6    5  -5          B      True      -      +
7    4 -10          B      True      -      +
8    3   8          B      True      -      +
9    2  10          A     False    NaN    NaN
10   0  11          A     False    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, yet when another True sequence appears, it' doesn't re-calculate the interval

Comment: @YedayaSchwalm you can change the condition for the groupby for example `.groupby(mask_c.ne(mask_c.shift()).cumsum())`

Comment: I assume the above suggestion worked? If you want me to update the output please update the question's example ;)